# Can't Inhibit deprecation warnings in PromiseKit added throu CocoaPods

Tags: xcode7, cocoapods, promisekit

I'm tring to use PromiseKit throu CocoaPods in my project. Minimum deployment target in projsect is setted to 9.0.

**Problem**

I'm getting deprecation warnings in PromiseKit which I'm trying to rid of.
Warnings appear in  in `UIActionSheet+Promise.swift`, `UIAlertView+Promise.swift`, `NSURLConnection+Promise.swift`.

[image: Warnings]

Things I've done:

1. I've setted  `Pods > Building settings > Deprecated Function` to **No**

[image: No]

2. Add `inhibit_all_warnings!` to Podfile and reinstall pod

   **Podfile**

   use_frameworks!
   inhibit_all_warnings!

   pod "PromiseKit", "~> 3.0", :inhibit_warnings => true

**Question**

I'm doing something wrong? Is there another way to do that?